# Line defined as start and lenght + orientation differs from start and end point definition - wrong orientation calculation?

Tags: c++, math, 3d, orientation, quaternions

I am trying to write some position/orientation methods for my small & simple 3d-space calculation library. But I'm stuck on the following problem.

I store 3d line as `start` and `end` points. However it should be possible to store it as `start` point and line's `length` + `orientation` as well (it's just a good example to test if orientation calculations works).

By `orientation` I mean rotation from the initial "0" orientation (which places the `end` at `start + [0,legth,0]`). So I first rotate the `[0,length,0]` by orientation and then add `start` to it to get `end` point.

The problem is, my orientation calculations fails somewhere. After calculating the orientation I get different ending point.

I use **left-handed coordinate system with Y-axis pointing up**, but I don't think it's important here.

Here's the code (I've tried to name the methods in the way you can check if the steps are ok; here's the [full source code](http://pastebin.com/SH3Rfuis) if you want to compile it yourself):

```
Point3D start = { 5.0f, 4.0f, 7.0f };
Point3D end = { 15.0f, 6.0f, 14.0f };

Point3D direction = (end - start);
std::wcout << L"Direction: "; direction.output();

float angle = Point3D(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f).getAngleToAnotherVectorInRadians(direction);
Point3D axis = direction.getCrossProduct(Point3D(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)).getNormalized();
Quaternion o = Quaternion(AxisAngle(axis, angle));

std::wcout << L"\nAxisAngle: ";  AxisAngle(axis, angle).output();
std::wcout << L"\nOrientation: "; o.output();

//test - end2 should be equal to end
Point3D offset(0.0f, (end - start).getLengthAsVector(), 0.0f);
offset = o.rotatePoint(offset);
std::wcout << L"\nOffset: "; offset.output();
Point3D end2 = start + offset;
std::wcout << L"\nEnd2: "; end2.output();
```

The code produces such output (without a comments, of course):

```
Direction: {10, 2, 7} //looks ok
AxisAngle: {{-0.573462, 0, 0.819232}, 1.40839}
Orientation: {-0.371272, 0, 0.530388, 0.762132}
Offset: {-10, 2, -7} //Almost! It should be {10, 2, 7}
End2: {-5, 6, -9.53674e-07} //Wrong! It should be { 15, 6, 14 }
```

In case that all steps are ok but there are some mistakes in methods' implementations I post here the important code for classes (so you can reproduce the problem): `Point3D, AxisAngle, Quaternion`.

**I highly believe that problem(s) lay(s) in my main steps or in `AxisAngle` calculations.** I think that `AxisAngle` to `Quaternion` transformation is ok (but I pass the wrong `AxisAngle` to `Quaternion` constructor).

The `Point3D`:

```
struct Point3D {
protected:
    float x, y, z;

public:
    Point3D() : x(0.0f), y(0.0f), z(0.0f) {}
    Point3D(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
    void output() { std::wcout << L"{" << x << L", " << y << L", " << z << L"}"; }
    Point3D operator-(const Point3D &point) const {
        Point3D temp;
        temp.setX(getX() - point.getX());
        temp.setY(getY() - point.getY());
        temp.setZ(getZ() - point.getZ());
        return temp;
    }
    Point3D operator+ (const Point3D &value) const {
        Point3D temp;
        temp.setX(getX() + value.getX());
        temp.setY(getY() + value.getY());
        temp.setZ(getZ() + value.getZ());
        return temp;
    }
    inline float getX() const { return x; } inline float getY() const { return y; } inline float getZ() const { return z; }
    inline void setX(float x) { this->x = x; } inline void setY(float y) { this->y = y; } inline void setZ(float z) { this->z = z; }

    inline float getLengthAsVector() const {
        return sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    }
    inline Point3D getCrossProduct(const Point3D &anotherVector) const {
        //based on: http://www.sciencehq.com/physics/vector-product-multiplying-vectors.html
        return Point3D(
            y * anotherVector.z - anotherVector.y * z,
            z * anotherVector.x - anotherVector.z * x,
            x * anotherVector.y - anotherVector.x * y
            );
    }
    inline float getDotProduct(const Point3D &anotherVector) const {
        //based on: https://www.ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/107/Vectors/DOTCROS.HTM
        return x * anotherVector.x + y * anotherVector.y + z * anotherVector.z;
    }
    inline float getAngleToAnotherVectorInRadians(const Point3D &anotherVector) const {
        //based on: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974178/how-to-calculate-the-angle-between-2-vectors-in-3d-space-given-a-preset-function
        return acos(getDotProduct(anotherVector) / (getLengthAsVector() * anotherVector.getLengthAsVector()));
    }
    Point3D getNormalized() const {
        float length = std::abs(sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z));
        Point3D result(x / length, y / length, z / length);
        return result;
    }
};
```

The `AxisAngle`:

```
class AxisAngle {
protected:
    Point3D axis;
    float angleInRadians;

public:
    AxisAngle(const AxisAngle &other) { axis = other.axis; angleInRadians = other.angleInRadians; }
    AxisAngle::AxisAngle(float x, float y, float z, float angleInRadians) {
        this->axis = Point3D(x, y, z);
        this->angleInRadians = angleInRadians;
    }
    AxisAngle::AxisAngle(const Point3D &axis, float angleInRadians) {
        this->axis = axis;
        this->angleInRadians = angleInRadians;
    }

    Point3D getAxis() const { return axis; }
    float getAngleInRadians() const { return angleInRadians; }

    void output() { std::wcout << L"{";  axis.output(); std::wcout << L", " << angleInRadians << L"}"; }

};
```

And last but not least, `Quaternion`:

```
class Quaternion {
protected:
    float x; float y; float z; float w;

public:
    Quaternion() { x = 0.0f; y = 0.0f; z = 0.0f; w = 1.0f; }
    Quaternion(const Quaternion &other) { x = other.x; y = other.y; z = other.z; w = other.w; }
    Quaternion(float x, float y, float z, float w) { this->x = x; this->y = y; this->z = z; this->w = w; }
    Quaternion(const AxisAngle &axisAngle) {
        Point3D axis = axisAngle.getAxis();
        float angleInRadians = axisAngle.getAngleInRadians();
        x = sin(angleInRadians / 2) * axis.getX();
        y = sin(angleInRadians / 2) * axis.getY();
        z = sin(angleInRadians / 2) * axis.getZ();
        w = cos(angleInRadians / 2);
        normalizeIt();
    }

    float getLength() const {
        return sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z + w*w);
    }

    void normalizeIt() {
        float length = getLength();
        x = x / length;
        y = y / length;
        z = z / length;
        w = w / length;
    }

    Quaternion getConjugated() const {
        return Quaternion(-x, -y, -z, w);
    }

    Quaternion multiply(Quaternion by) {
        //"R" for result
        float wR = w * by.getW() - x * by.getX() - y * by.getY() - z * by.getZ();
        float xR = x * by.getW() + w * by.getX() + y * by.getZ() - z * by.getY();
        float yR = y * by.getW() + w * by.getY() + z * by.getX() - x * by.getZ();
        float zR = z * by.getW() + w * by.getZ() + x * by.getY() - y * by.getX();
        return Quaternion(xR, yR, zR, wR);
    }

    //rotate Point3D p around [0,0,0] with this Quaternion
    Point3D rotatePoint(Point3D p) const {
        Quaternion temp = multiply(p).multiply(getConjugated());
        return Point3D(temp.getX(), temp.getY(), temp.getZ());

        //G: P' = Q(P-G)Q' + G <- to rotate P around G with Quaternion
    }

    Quaternion multiply(Point3D r) const {
        float wR = -x * r.getX() - y * r.getY() - z * r.getZ();
        float xR = w * r.getX() + y * r.getZ() - z * r.getY();
        float yR = w * r.getY() + z * r.getX() - x * r.getZ();
        float zR = w * r.getZ() + x * r.getY() - y * r.getX();
        return Quaternion(xR, yR, zR, wR);
    }

    inline float getX() const { return x; } inline void setX(float x) { this->x = x; }
    inline float getY() const { return y; } inline void setY(float y) { this->y = y; }
    inline float getZ() const { return z; } inline void setZ(float z) { this->z = z; }
    inline float getW() const { return w; } inline void setW(float w) { this->w = w; }

    void output() { std::wcout << L"{" << x << L", " << y << L", " << z << L", " << w << L"}"; }
};
```

In case somebody would ask: **I do want to use quaternions.** They may not look 100% needed here, but storing 3d object's orientation as quaternion has many benefits in more complex computations (and most game engines / 3d software use it as well "under the mask").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your axis has the wrong orientation. It should be:

```
Point3D axis = Point3D(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f).getCrossProduct(direction).getNormalized();
```

Use the two left-hand rules to figure out the correct order.